# How to fetch session stored value when IIS Express stops

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one ASP.Net MVC - 5 application and in one of the place I have stored value in Session as

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"] = user.SessionID;`

I am able to access the value as

`int x = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];`

But I want to access the same value when I stop the IIS Express. I know that `Application_End` gets called from `Global.asax`.

```
  protected void Application_End()
        {
           int x = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];
        }
```

But the value of **x** comes out to be null. Is there any particular reason that session value is not available in Application_End(). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

The session is already disposed by the time Application_End is called.  Try using Session_End if you need to get information before IISExpress has totally stopped.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Unbreakable: Bear in mind that this still only works as long as everything is functioning as it's supposed to. If the App Pool crashes, the server shuts down unexpectedly (power failure, for instance), there's no opportunity to catch anything. I'm not sure what you're trying to use this for, but just make sure that it's not an application requirement.

Answer (score 1):

By default sessions are stored in-memory (`InProc`) mode. When your application shuts down all the memory associated with it is wiped. This means that everything you might have stored in the session is gone. That's the reason why in production you should absolutely never use `InProc` mode but rather off-load the storage to a separate service or SqlServer. If for some reason your application is recycled by IIS (for example due to some inactivity or high load), then all session data is gone.